# Unable to share on WeeChat

Tags: android, weechat

I'm trying to share media by weechat sdk. But i'm getting this message:

> The app is blocked from being shared. Unable to share on WeeChat

Also in logcat i'm gettings this error. Btw i generated app signature key in terminal and also generate it in [this](https://github.com/mike623/cordova-WeChat-meteor-sharing/blob/master/README.md) app. Keys are the same but still gettings this error

```
E/ActivityManager: Transaction too large, intent: Intent { flg=0x18800000 cmp=com.tencent.mm/.plugin.base.stub.WXEntryActivity (has extras) }, extras size: 328448, icicle size: 0
2020-02-14 16:35:33.924 17794-17794/? E/Instrumentation: Uninitialized ActivityThread, likely app-created Instrumentation, disabling AppComponentFactory
    java.lang.Throwable
        at android.app.Instrumentation.getFactory(Instrumentation.java:1225)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
        at com.tencent.mm.splash.k.newActivity(SourceFile:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of research. I found out that it is impossible to share using weechat sdk in applications not registered in China